# Prevent direct-linking to .zip files

Tags: download

I'ld like to prevent direct-linking to .zip files I offer for download on my website.
I'm reading posts for hours now but I'm not sure which method is the best to achieve that. PHP seems not to be safe and htaccess refferer can be empty etc.
Which method do you guys use or would suggest?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hotlinking/

and: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/2787.htm

Comment: Note the first there is no different than any other referrer check. And the second doesn't really explain how to prevent the hot-linker from ripping the link out of the redirected-to page.

Answer (score 1):

Referrer checking is one option, but as you noted they can be empty or [spoofed](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/refcontrol/).

Another possibility is to set a cookie when someone visits normal pages on your site, and check for that when the person tries to download the zip file. This could be gotten around (e.g. by the hot-linker embedding an appropriate cookie-setter page as a 1x1 image along size the hot link), but it's less likely they'll figure it out. It'll also exclude people who block cookies, of course.

Another possibility is to generate limited-time-access URLs on the download page, something along the lines of `http://example.com/download.php?file=file.zip&code=some-random-string-here`. The link would only be usable for a small number of downloads and/or a short period of time, after which it would no longer function.

Comment: @Michael if serving zip files through php is a viable option for you, Anomie's solution is definitely smarter. Provide links that expire after a short period of time. You could even encode IP information into your random string, but this would be dangerous as a legitimate client could easily switch to a different IP _during_ a session.

Comment: Yes, PHP viable for me. The only thing is I read a lot of XSS problems with that. How does a safe download.php look like?

Comment: @magma Is this what you meant with expired links through PHP? Link: http://snipplr.com/view/205/download-file/ Please let me know.

Comment: @Michael not at all. The idea (that was actually first introduced by Anomie) has nothing to do with http cache expire tags. See this thread: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=155358.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to understand the tutorial but it's to complex. Are there any good pre build scripts you would suggest for a beginner?

Comment: Can anybody please help me build this? Link: http://tanksoftware.com/tutes/leechprotection.html My english isn't good enought to make it work alone. :/